# How do you avoid interrupt starvation in a nested interrupt system?

Tags: embedded, interrupt, scheduling, interrupt-handling, starvation

I am learning about interrupts and couldn't understand what happens when there are too many interrupts to a point where the CPU can't process the foreground loop or complete the existing interrupts. I read through this article https://www.cs.utah.edu/~regehr/papers/interrupt_chapter.pdf but didn't completely understand how a scheduler would help, if there are simply too many interrupts?

Do we switch to a faster CPU if the interrupts can not be missed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you had to switch to a faster CPU!
You had to ensure that there is enough time for the mainloop. Therefore it is really important to keep your Interrupt service as short as possible and do some CPU workloads tests.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, any time there is contention over a shared resource, there is the possibility of starvation. The schedulers discussed in the paper limit the interrupt rate, thus ensuring some interrupt-free processing time during each interval. During high activity periods, interrupt handling is disabled, and the scheduler switches to polling mode where it interrogates the state of the interrupt request lines periodically, effectively throttling the stream of interrupts. The operating system strives to do as little as possible in each interrupt handler - tasks are often simply queued so they can be handled later at a different stage. There are many considerations and trade-offs that go into any scheduling algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Overall you need a clue of how much time each part of your program consumes. This is pretty easy to measure in practice live with an oscilloscope. If you activate a GPIO when entering and de-activate it when leaving the interrupt, you don't only get to see how much time the ISR consumes, but also how often it kicks in. If you do this for each ISR you get a good idea how much time they need. You can then do something similar in main(), to get a rough estimate of the complete execution cycle of the program, main + interrupts.

As for the best solution, it is obviously to reduce the amount of interrupts. Use polling if possible. Use DMA. Use serial peripherals (UART, CAN etc) that are hardware-buffered instead of interrupt-intensive ones. Use hardware PWM instead of output compare timers. And so on. These things need to be considered early on when you pick a suitable MCU for your project. If you picked the wrong MCU, then you'll obviously have to change. Twiddling with the CPU clock sounds like quick & dirty fix. Get the design right instead.